# Facebook: Javascript API sometimes doesn't load

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

Once every several times the calls to the Facebook API are not finished (or maybe not even made). For example I am counting the number of user's friends, that also use my app, but this seems to be never calculated. I tried to investigate this issue, but there are no errors in the Chrome console. Have you ever encountered such behavior and know, how to fix it?

**EDIT**

Here are some details, I get:

```
error_code 190
error_msg Error validating access token: The session is invalid because the user logged out or because auth.expireSession was invoked
```

The point is I am logging out as one user and then logging in as another. Why is it then Facebook treating it as a logged out user? Furthermore, everything works, if I then refresh the page.

**EDIT2**

This are some code snippets:

```
function facebookInit(config) {
  Config = config;

  FB.init({
    appId: Config.appId,
    xfbml: true,
    status: true,
    cookie: true,
    channelUrl:
      window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + '/channel.html'
  });
  FB.Event.subscribe('auth.sessionChange', handleSessionChange);
  FB.Canvas.setSize();

  // ensure we're always running on apps.facebook.com
  if (window == top) { goHome(); }
}


window.fbAsyncInit = function() { 
    facebookInit({{ js_conf|safe }}) 
    afterSDK()  
};
```

and the problem arises here:

```
var query = "SELECT '' " +
        "FROM user " +
        "WHERE is_app_user = \"1\" AND " +
              "uid IN (SELECT uid2 " +
                      "FROM friend WHERE uid1 = {{ user.user_id }})"
FB.api({'method': 'fql.query', 'query': query}, 
       function(response){
```

This code is called inside `afterSDK()` function. The response might bring error, rather than the number of friends using app.

Comment: What calls are you making? Is this a recent error that used to work?

Comment: Nope, it always has been like this. From time to time it simply doesn't work.

Comment: What does your code look like? Are you trying to use the access token for anything? If so how do you get it?

Comment: I added some snippets of code, that seems not to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me take a stab at this.

I think the issue is because your logging out a user, and logging in another. There may be an issue occurring because Facebook does not detect that the other user has logged out, and thinks its the same person. This may clear up that issue:

```
FB.logout(function(response) {
  // user is now logged out
});
```

Run that to ensure the user is logged out, then try to move from there

Hopefully this helps a little bit.

[Here is the facebook logout method](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.logout/)

You can also look [at this previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5840552/facebook-php-sdk-error-validating-access-token) about refreshing a session (though its in PHP and i don't know the JS equivalent)

Comment: But when exactly should I call this? Before I run init method? But won't I then have my current (the right one) user logged out and nothing will work?

Comment: No. The `init` method needs to be run first (you may need to run it again, but if its not first then I think you will get errors). I may be confused on what you are doing though. Aren't you trying to log out as one user and in as another one?

Comment: I am. I am using account->log out from facebook. Then I enter url of my app and click 'Login', authenticate and only then should the init be called. That's how it works.

Comment: Try running the `FB.logout` first then. If your account is already logged in, then the `Init` may not matter (I was always under the impression that you needed that call first to run any facebook application on apps.facebook). You could also attempt to debug it through `FB.getLoginStatus()` [this link for more info](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/). This method can give you access to all of the access tokens, FB ids, ect. That way you can try comparing FB Ids and see which user is logged in when you hit the `afterSDK()` method